# Overflow scroll x and visible y

Tags: css, overflow, tailwind-css

My question is related to this setup: https://play.tailwindcss.com/47UVFMGtao

When you hover a TagName element, a tooltip appears … however, the row is scrollable in x direction. This is mandatory.
However, when I set this overflow behavior, the tooltip is not visible on hover and also to scroll….

I want to let the tooltip overflow the row in y direction while I can scroll in x direction , how is this possible?

As I see related to the answers, my question is not leading to my idea.

**⭐️ What I want is this behaviour:**

[image]

Not this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

you need to give a fixed width to the div wrapper like below:

```css
.flex.w-full.flex-row.items-center.gap-x-5.overflow-x-scroll.bg-indigo-100.p-5 {
    height: 150px;
}
```

This will allow the tooltip to be fully visible and also there will be no scrollers added to the y-axis.

Comment: The row should not be increased by height, the tooltip should be visible above the row borders and beyond.

Comment: nothing like that is evident from the question..

Comment: I have edited my question, please check again and try to help me if you want.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you can hide the scrollbar by adding this utility in `index.css` file.

```
@layer utilities {
    /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    .no-scrollbar {
      -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

Then you just add the class `no-scrollbar`  in main div.

Secondly now just scroll vertically to get your tooltip visible.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex w-full flex-row items-center gap-x-5 overflow-x-scroll no-scrollbar bg-indigo-100 p-5">
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100 z-20">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
  <div class="group relative rounded bg-white p-2">
    <span>#TagName</span>
    <div class="absolute bottom-0 left-0 translate-y-full scale-0 whitespace-nowrap rounded bg-indigo-500 p-2 text-white group-hover:scale-100">info panel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is not solving my problem, I have edited my question, please check again and try to help me if you want.

Comment: You can not put any element over horizontal scrollbar